# AddAsync() method is missing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core. I want to create an async method which will create new user in my database, i have included all the libraries I need, but some methods that are supposed to work with database are missing, I have almost every async method but i am missing AddAsync and RemoveAsync. When I type AddAsync manually I get the following error message: "Error   CS1061  'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'AddAsync' and no accessible extension method 'AddAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The class where the method is created has following code and libraries included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class1 : Interface1
    {
        public async Task AddKorisnik(Korisnici k)
        {
            using (ExtentEntities context = new ExtentEntities())
            {
                context.Korisnici.AddAsync();
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class where the DbContext is used is following:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class ExtentEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ExtentEntities()
            : base("name=ExtentEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Korisnici> Korisnici { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous with adding an object to an in-memory `DbSet`. Use the synchronous `Add` method instead.

Comment: There is no `AddAsync()` or `RemoveAsync()` method on `DbContext`. It only goes to the DB upon `SaveChangesAsync()`, hence there's no reason to provide `async` versions for `Add()/Remove()`

Comment: @haim770 There is `AddAsync` on DbContext in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't compile is that `AddAsync` is not a method on `DbSet<T>`, but on `DbContext`. However, you should not use this method.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Whats the `AddAsync` method for again? Was it only when you table needed to seed prior right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing asynchronous with adding an object to an in-memory `DbSet<T>`. You should use the synchronous `Add` method to do this.

`SaveChangesAsync()` is the method that actually connects asynchronously to the underlying database.

Comment: What about this? It exists in documentation within DBContext
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-2.1

Comment: @AhmetHalilović The documentation you linked to states "This method is async only to allow special value generators to access the database asynchronously. **For all other cases the non async method should be used**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Dai What do you mean under the special value generators?

Comment: @AhmetHalilović Please read the documentation that you linked to, it explains everything relating to your question.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-2.1) is the documentation for the async version of the `DbSet<T>` class that should be used in your case.

Comment: `AddAsync` is a method on *DbContext*, not on *DbSet*. As the answer and documentation states, you should not use it.

Comment: So I should use the normal Add method and conclude it with SaveChangesAsync?

Comment: @AhmetHalilović: Yes.